# C++: how to strip a "set" by removing multiple elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, stl, set

In STL algorithm, there're several "set" operations like set_union, set_difference, set_intersection, set_symmetric_difference，but I wish to do between 2 vectors:

```
vector<int> A={1,2,3,4};
vector<int> B={1,3};
```

I wish to get A-B so A-B={2,4}.

Is there a convenient way to do this "minus"?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference), no? You already mention it, so why don't you think you can use it? It only requires that your `vector`s are sorted, which yours are.

Comment: Oh I think I get it: you think you can only use the `set_` algorithms on a `std::set`? Not true. The containers and algorithms in the Standard Library don't interact directly, but via *iterators*, so the algorithms don't need to care about the exact type of the container they are operating on. If you want the result to go into a `vector` as well, use [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to create the output iterator for the algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You absolutely can use the `set_` algorithms on a `vector`, as long as the `vector` is sorted. You can then use [`back_inserter()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to push the output into another `vector`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> v2 {1, 3};
    std::vector<int> out;
    std::set_difference(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), // the first vector...
                        std::begin(v2), std::end(v2), // ...minus the second...
                        std::back_inserter(out));     // ...is stored into here
    for(auto i : out) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Prints:

```
2 4
```

(Note this version assumes that it can compare the elements using `<` and that the elements are sorted with respect to that - which is obviously fine in your case).

Comment: But you cannot use the set algorithms on an `std::unordered_set`, which sometimes seems to confuse people.